# Easy way to align two grids next to each other?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Is there an easy way to have two grids laid out side by side (one on the left and one on the right, both taking up 50% of the available width) without enclosing them in another container, or do I need to place them in another container and lay them out inside of there? For example, in web development you can float items so that they are aligned side by side without necessarily having them inside a parent container which is exactly what I want.

Comment: No. Put them inside a parent Grid. What is your reason `not` to do that?

Comment: I'm not against doing that, I'm just trying to learn and get a deeper understanding of what's possible and the reasons behind them. I couldn't find anything elsewhere on the web that talked about this so I figured the people here of all places would know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they have to be in some sort of container. This is because some containers are designed to have precisely **one** child. For example, a [`Window`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has a [`Content`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), not [`Children`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.children%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). `Content`'s type is `object` and is documented as being "text or a single object", so if you try to put two items inside it (e.g. both your `Grid`s), it will not compile.

For something like what you want, I'd probably include a simple `Grid` with two columns. The default widths will mean that they each take 50% of the width.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Columns>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.Columns>
    <Grid><!-- grid one --></Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1"><!-- grid two --></Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks, the extra explanation of why this is the case really helps!